# Why not find the element 'a'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Get the 'div' element but same way don't get the 'a' element.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bf

# link :
url = "https://www.imdb.com/search/name/?gender=male,female&ref_=nv_tp_cel"


Response = requests.get(url)

soup = bf(Response.text,'lxml')

div = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "lister-item-content")


a_tag = div.find_all('a')

print(a_tag)
```

I want to print all 'a' element from  'div' element.

Comment: Print the div content. Are there any a tags?

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah, there are 'a' tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through each `div` element, then iterate through each `a` child with `div.findChildren`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bf

# link :
url = "https://www.imdb.com/search/name/?gender=male,female&ref_=nv_tp_cel"


Response = requests.get(url)

soup = bf(Response.text,'lxml')

divs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "lister-item-content")

for div in divs:
    a_tags = div.findChildren('a')

    for a_tag in a_tags:
        print (a_tag)
```

Which would print something like:

> ```
> ...
> <a href="/title/tt0356910/"> Mr. &amp; Mrs. Smith
> </a>
> <a href="/title/tt0137523">Fight Club</a>
> <a href="/title/tt1210166">Moneyball</a>
> <a href="/title/tt0240772">Ocean's Eleven</a>
> <a href="/name/nm0000522"> Vanessa Marcil
> </a>
> <a href="/title/tt0117500/"> The Rock
> </a>
> ```